# Motion in a plane situation

Tags: homework-and-exercises, kinematics, acceleration, velocity, calculus

There is something weird I find about the following situation. Suppose a particle has the $X$-coordinate $= 2+2t+4t²$ and $Y$-coordinate $= 4t+8t²$. So it's velocity in $X$ is $2+8t$ and velocity in $Y$ is $4+16t$. Acceleration in $X$ is $8$ and acceleration in $Y$ is $16$. Now I know this will follow a parabolic path in the $XY$ plane, but there are some relations we can obtain, namely $\frac{V_y}{V_x}=2$ and similarly $\frac{A_y}{A_x}=2$.

Does this mean that the velocity and acceleration act along same line? What's the significance of the ratio of velocities being independent of time?

I feel like there ought to be something special about this motion but I just can't point my finger at it.

Comment: Hint: Start from $a V_x + b V_y =0$ for known constants $(a,b)$ and see what kind of paths you can get from there. This type of constraint is called a [Pfaffian constraint](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pfaffian_constraint)

Comment: PS. This is the first question I saw here tagged with [kinematics] and actually being about kinematics and not projectile motion (which isn't kinematics but dynamics).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Summary

In this situation the particle is constrained to move in a straight line. You can confirm this by plotting the trajectory.

### Details

Consider the velocity vector $\vec{v}(t) = \pmatrix{V_x \\ V_y}$ subject to the constraint $2 V_x - V_y = 0$. Now imagine the particle is in some sort of track and there is a constraint force $\vec{F} = \pmatrix{F_x \\ F_y}$ keeping it on the track. This force does *no work* and so the power of the force must be zero

$$ P = \vec{F} \cdot \vec{v} = F_x V_x + F_y V_y =0 $$

So if the force is proportional to $ \vec{F} = F \pmatrix{2 \\ -1}$ it would produce no power and it would act like the constraint force of the track.

$$ P = \vec{F} \cdot \vec{v} = 2 F V_x - F V_y = F (2 V_x - V_y) = 0 $$

So the particle moves along a track described by the normal (perpendicular) vector $$\vec{n} = \pmatrix{ 2  \\ -1 }$$

But since the normal vector is *constant* the track must be a straight line (since any curve would bend the normal vector).

A particle constrained on a straight line will always have velocity and acceleration vectors tangent to the line.

You can decompose the motion along the track, using the tangent vector $\vec{e} = \pmatrix{ 1 \\ 2 }$ and stating

$$ \vec{v}(t) = \vec{e}\, v(t) $$
$$ \require{cancel} \vec{a}(t) = \frac{\vec{e}}{\| \vec{e} \|}\, \dot{v}(t) + \frac{\vec{n}}{\| \vec{n} \|} \cancel{ \frac{v^2}{\rho }} $$

The reason the second part cancels is because the radius of curvature $\rho = \infty$.

Comment: I don't understand the normal vector. Can you explain in simpler terms? I am not familiar with this level of vector algebra.

Comment: @DhruviKataria - Normal is another word for perpendicular. The force to keep an object on a track _has_ to be perpendicular to the velocity at all times (to keep it from doing any work). Here you have a situation where the constraint force vector is constant, and thus the direction of the path is constant also.

Comment: @JAlex- Understood, thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

When you say $\frac{v_y }{v_x} = 2$ or $\frac{a_y }{a_x} = 2$ you automatically refer to the ratio of the **magnitudes** of velocity and acceleration. This is because division of vectors is not defined in kinematics.So from these relations you cannot make any conclusion about the direction of acceleration or velocity.

Comment: Okay. But doesn't it atleast mean that direction of velocity and acceleration are same at each position of particle?

Comment: Actually now I realize that can't be possible or it would move in straight line. So why is ratio of velocities and accelerations same?

Comment: @DhruviKataria - because speed is independent of the rate of change of speed.

Comment: It is not the ratio of magnitudes, but the ratio of components. The magnitude is $\sqrt{V_x^2+V_y^2}$ which is not constant.

Comment: @JAlex- Okay I think I understand

Comment: What I meant in my answer was that its ratio of the magnitudes of components in x and y direction of velocity and acceleration respectively and since its a scalar expression we cannot derive any conclusion from it about the direction of motion.To find direction/path followed by body we must find trajectory by eliminating the parameter 't' from equation of x and y.

Answer (score 0):

One thing worth noticing is that we can prove the motion is linear pretty directly. We have two equations:
$$X = 2+2t+4t^2$$
and
$$Y = 4t+8t^2$$
If we divide the $Y$ equation by 2, we get
$$Y/2 = 2t+4t^2$$
Substituting into the $X$ equation, we get
$$X = 2 + Y/2$$
or
$$Y = 2X - 4$$
which is the equation of a line.

Another thing to notice is that an acceleration can only change the direction of velocity if it is not parallel with that velocity. There must be a component of the acceleration that points to the side of the velocity to change its direction. When you find that $V_X/V_Y = A_X/A_Y = 2$, you are proving exactly that the acceleration and velocity are parallel.